# Simulink: simulation time buffer issue with scope

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am streaming audio out of a simulink block at 1024 samples per frame at 44100/1024 time intervals.   When I connect a scope to this buffer, I don't get anything displayed and I believe I need to feed the scope a sample at a time at the 44100 interval rate.

Is there a block that can do this?  or can the scope be configured to accept the buffer and treat the contents appropriately?

Comment: have you unchecked the *display last 5000 values*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the DSP System Toolbox then use the [Vector Scope](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/vectorscope.html), not the standard Scope block.

Alternatively use the [Unbuffer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/unbuffer.html) block to generate time based signals and feed them to the standard Scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I perfectly understand your problem but if yes, the answer may be easy:

1. Right click on the scope and choose "block parameter scope" (or double click to enter in the scope).
2. Then on top left of the scope, click on the gear icon (properties of the scope).
3. Then, in the "input processing" part, you will  have the choice between frame based functionning or sample based functionning. Choose frame based and it should work.

I mention that sometimes i have a bug with my version of simulink: choosing frame based and going back to sample based crash matlab. I just restart matlab and everything works fine again.

The "unbuffer option" proposed in the accepted answer will work too but may slow down a lot the scope. If data are big and speed is important, just choose the option "frame based" in the properties of the scope as explained: it just works well.

Below the picture of the option to choose.

[image]